# iPad SDK: How to play a series of videos with MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ipad

I am wondering how to most efficiently play a series of video with MPMoviePlayerViewController?

For example, I would like to play in a series the following:

Video1.mp4
Video2.mp4
Video3.mp4

and so on...

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSNotificationCenter` to monitor for the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` notification. Then, set up the player with the next item you wish to play.

Comment: I do have the callback registered. I do have the filenames in an array I can track. Are you suggesting adding the play methods to the  
MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification? Thanks.

   //---play movie---
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [playerViewController moviePlayer];
    [player play];

Comment: Yes, but you'll want to use `-setContentURL:` to set it to the next movie, then play it.

Comment: Thanks but still having issues. For some reason I cannot access the array that holds the fileNames. This code works in viewDidLoad but throws exception from the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotificaition. This is the code to access an array of strings. How can I access this array from the callback?  
 NSString *string = [arrayBrotherPirateEnglish objectAtIndex: 2]; 2010-07-26 14:13:17.391 BookReaderJuly23[51927:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFType objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5340b10'

Comment: You'll need to make sure you're retaining the array so it stays around long enough to use when the notification is called.

Comment: Added retain to the array. Now, the movieFinished callback is not even being fired and I'm getting this.


2010-07-26 21:54:06.544 EJStoriesVol1[67297:207] *** -[VideoPlaybackViewController moviePlayBackDidFinish:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5362580
2010-07-26 21:54:06.551 EJStoriesVol1[67297:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[VideoPlaybackViewController moviePlayBackDidFinish:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5362580'

Comment: Please disregard above comment. Name change problem.

Comment: i made all my instance variables properties and now all is good. one question? should i remove the observer:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification before each new video is played or after the entire series?

Comment: After the whole series, otherwise you'll stop getting the notifications. Since you're using the same MoviePlayer for all the videos, you don't have to change the notification stuff in between.

Answer (score 0):

You can register for the notification `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` with `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]`. Once you receive that notification, just load the next video and start playback.

Have a look at the respective class documentations for additional details.